# How to move tabs in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

Every once in a while, I need to "refresh" my shell session by closing it and opening a new one. Unfortunately the terminal tab ends up at the very end of tab bar, so I need to move it back to where it was (I use command-left and command-right to move between tabs a lot, so order is important). Since I am on a 13" screen, I keep my terminal maximized. When I move the tab with a mouse, if I move it even a little bit too much, the tab splits into its own, maximized, window and I am unable to re-attach it (because maximized == fullscreen now, right?). So I have to close the new window and start over again. Is there some way to change tab order without accidental detaching?

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't _have_ _to_ start all over again, you can use "Merge All Windows" command to reattach the tab. Unless of course you have multiple Terminal windows.

Comment: Well, it is a brand new shell, I might as well close it and hit command-T again.

Comment: I am currently figuring out tmux as a way to avoid this whole issue completely. But it seems like such an ugly side effect of "maximize == fullscreen" that I thought there must be some way to deal with it.

Comment: @MadWombat Use alt-maximize button to restore the previous behavior (not fullscreen!)

Comment: Good thing to know, but that is not the solution I am looking for. I want my terminal full screen and I want to move tabs around without hassle.

Comment: The trick of me while in Full Screen is to keep upwards pressure, so to speak, as I slide a tab with the mouse. This keeps it from detaching from the window. Unlike the slightest move downwards detaches the tab to a new window.